# Insertion sort arraylist, sorting numbers ascending and names alphabetically

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, insertion-sort

So I have an arraylist of dogs that I want to sort by tail-length and also by names in alphabetical order. 
I can get it to sort either by tail-length *or* names, but I can't manage to get them both. Heres my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class DogSorter {

    public void sort(ArrayList<Dog> dogs) {

        for(int i =1; i < dogs.size(); i++) {
            Dog current = dogs.get(i);
            int j = i-1;
            while ((j > -1 ) && ((dogs.get(j).compareTailLengthTo(current)) == 1)) {
                dogs.set(j+1, dogs.get(j));
                j--;

            }
            dogs.set(j+1, current);
        }
    }
}
```

In Dog Class:

```
 public double compareTailLengthTo(Dog dog) {
        int res = 0;
        if (this.tailLength < dog.getTailLength()) {
            res = -1;
        }
        if (this.tailLength > dog.getTailLength()) {
            res = 1;
        }
        return res;

    }
```

What I tried for sorting the names (also in Dog Class):

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Dog other) {
       int compareInt = this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(other.name);
       if(compareInt < 0) {return -1;}
       if (compareInt > 0 ) {return 1;}
       return 0;

    }
```

I tried simply replacing .compareTailLengthTo with .compareTo in my sort-method just to see if it would work on its own which it did. I then tried to check both by just adding another &&-check after the .compareTailLengthTo, but then only the last check would work. (English is not my first language so I hope my explanation makes sense here, apologies if it doesn't).

So, after this wall of text, I guess my question is: How do I sort multiple things using insertion sort?

(I apologize if this question has already been asked. I've been searching for hours now and haven't found an answer so I hope that's not the case though. I would also like to point out (in case it matters) that this is a school assignment and I'm restricted to insertion sort and I have to have the sort method in a separate class. Lastly, I'm a complete beginner at programming so please forgive me (but do correct me!) on any stupid mistakes.

Comment: First, compare by the primary attribute (name *or* tail-length); iff (if and only if) the result of that comparison is `0` should you then compare by the secondary attribute (tail-length *or* name).

Comment: Thank you Elliott, that was exactly what I needed :)